# Viewshed: why does a larger input cell size result in a larger viewshed area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, viewshed, cell-size

At Arc Desktop 10.7.1 I am conducting a viewshed analysis using the *Viewshed* tool. I am trying to understand how the *input* raster cell size affects the area covered by the *output* viewshed raster.

This screenshot illustrates my issue.  The yellow symbol, lower-right corner, is the single input point, with *OFFSETA* = 200 m.  I conducted two Viewshed analyses, one where the input raster was a 10-m **DSM** (blue output), and the other where the input raster was a 3-m **DSM** (red output, superimposed over the blue).  The input **DSMs** were generated from the same lidar source.

The screenshot includes a 3-m **DTM** hillshade as a viewing reference. It was not used in the analysis.

The blue and red viewsheds radiate across the body of water located in the screenshot center.  It is obvious that the viewsheds are influenced by forest along the southeast shoreline (the input **DSMs** are not shown here).  Thus, the general output trend makes sense: the shoreline tree canopy "shades" the water for a distance to the northwest, where the viewshed eventually comes down to the surface.

**QUESTION:**

I am surprised that the blue viewshed (10-m input **DSM**) covers such a greater extent than the red viewshed (3-m input **DSM**). I expected the blue viewshed to cover a *slightly* larger area simply due to the larger input cells.  But how to explain the tremendous output difference shown in the screenshot, particularly within the highlighted area?

I considered that perhaps the viewing angle is dependent on the input cell size.  But the ESRI *Viewshed* documentation simply states, "The visibility of each cell center is determined by comparing the altitude angle to the cell center with the altitude angle to the local horizon."  It does not mention a varying viewing angle.

A web search turned up nothing regarding input raster size and the resulting viewshed extent. I thus turn to SE for assistance.

[image]

Comment: Did you explore the actual altitude of your cells? There is certainly some differences in cells altitudes at a same point due the difference in resolution, e.g. some bumps may be diluted in larger cells or vice versa. What seems astonishing in your image, is that they seem to lay in a flat region. Could you check this altitude difference out?

Comment: Because larger cell result in a smoother surface, e.g. if the whole raster made of 1 cell, you'll see all of it.

Comment: s.k I'm not sure what you're asking.  If it helps, I did create the optional agl output raster when I ran the Viewshed tool.  Are you asking me to look at the difference between those agl rasters?

Comment: FelixP I subsequently re-ran the viewshed with a 30-m resolution input raster and, as before, the output viewshed was larger than the 10-m input.  All of this has got me wondering...What is the appropriate input cell size?  I may ask in a new SE question.

Comment: The answer is as small cell size as you computer can handle, because finer resolution better depicts real terrain.

Comment: Or perhaps as small as the source data is capable of resolving?  For example, my surface raster source is a lidar project.  I've reviewed the las stats, and I'm comfortable going down to a 3-m cell resolution.  Theoretically I could make the raster cell size smaller, but at the expense of data quality.